# Error: Install Failure: No manifest. Invalid package.Install Failure: No manifest

Tags: roku, brightscript

Hi I am just beginning with Roku development. I downloaded the sdk and have been trying to run an hello world application. I have a source folder and a manifest file. But I still keep getting the following error:

> Error: Install Failure: No manifest. Invalid package.Install Failure:
>   No manifest.

Here is the code for hello world:

```vb
sub Main()
  ' create our screen
  screen = CreateObject("roPosterScreen") 

  ' setup a message port so we can receive event information
  port = CreateObject("roMessagePort")
  screen.SetMessagePort(port)

  ' change the screen's message text
  screen.ShowMessage("Hello World!")
  screen.Show()

  ' start our event loop
  while true
    msg = Wait(0, port) ' wait for an event

    if type(msg) = "roPosterScreenEvent"
      ' we got a poster screen event
      if msg.isScreenClosed()
        ' the user closed the screen
        exit while
      end if
    end if
  end while

  screen.Close()
  ' any time all screens in a channel are closed, the channel will exit
end sub
```

**When I upload the examples that came with the sdk it works fine But when I try to replace the example app's Main function's code with above code I get the error specified above.**

I have been looking all over the internet about this  but did not help much. Any suggestions would be really appreciated.

Comment: Are you using BrightScript plugin for Eclipse to deploy?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This sounds like your files are not zipped "correctly" in the package. Make sure the `manifest` file is at top level in the zip and not in a subdirectory.

It's a common mistake people pointing at the project directory - right-click and zip it like so - but that includes the root directory name in the paths too. Get inside the project dir, select all files and `source` directory and zip this way instead.

Comment: [Roku Dev Guide](https://developer.roku.com/develop/getting-started/sdk-hello-world) If you compress (“zip”) the parent folder, the Developer Application Installer will return an error.

Answer (score 0):

If your bright script code has any fault, you will never get this error

> No manifest. Invalid package.Install Failure:

This error comes only when you try to upload invalid zip file.